# Grid for logic grid puzzles

Tags: grids, logicpuzzle

I'm looking for a way to draw the grid for a ["logic grid puzzle"](http://www.logic-puzzles.org/). There is a package called ["logic puzzle"](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/logicpuzzle) but that doesn't seem to include this type of logic puzzle.

Any idea(s)?

Comment: Looks like 'ordinary' tables?

Comment: I tried asking [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311101/grid-for-logic-grid-puzzles), @cfr.

Comment: @QuinnCulver: Linking to this question is ... (fill in yourself) ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is a starter only, not perfect yet: A 'weird' combination of `\multicolumn` and `\cline` and `\multirow` will provide a grid structure as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\tikzball}[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\shade[ball color=blue,#1] (0,-0.1) circle (0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newlength{\logpuzzlecellwidth}
\setlength{\logpuzzlecellwidth}{0.5cm}

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\vphantom{\tikzball}}l|l|*{10}{A{\logpuzzlecellwidth}|}}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}c|}{owners} & \multicolumn{5}{>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}c|}{breeds} \tabularnewline[1ex]
  \cline{3-12}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \rotatebox{90}{Arara} & \rotatebox{90}{Booktabs} & \rotatebox{90}{Colortable}  & \rotatebox{90}{Datetime} & \rotatebox{90}{etoolbox} & \rotatebox{90}{A} & \rotatebox{90}{B} & \rotatebox{90}{C}  & \rotatebox{90}{D} & \rotatebox{90}{E}  \tabularnewline
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{cats}}  & A & & & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-12}
  & B & & & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline  
  \cline{2-12}
  & C & & & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-12}
  & D & & & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-12}
  & E & & \tikzball & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{dogs}}  & A & & & & & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-7}
  & B & & & & & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-7}
  & C & & & & & \tikzball[ball color=red] & \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-7}
  & D & & & & & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-7}
  & E & & & & & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \tabularnewline
  \cline{1-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it'd look better if the cells were squares, though.

Comment: @Alenanno: yes, definitely. I will provide a better solution (later on)